# How do I rethrow an exception and preserve the stack trace?

Tags: dart

This code:

```dart
try {
  try {
    throw 1;
  } catch (e, s) {
    print("$e $s");
    throw e;
  }
} catch (e2, s2) {
  print("$e2 $s2");    
}
```

prints:

```
1 #0      main (file:///.../test.dart:34:7)

1 #0      main (file:///.../test.dart:37:7)
```

So the original stack trace is completely lost. Is there any way to rethrow with the stack trace preserved?

Comment: What happens if you just `rethrow`?

Comment: @Ladicek, is there a `rethrow` keyword in Dart?  I can't find evidence of it online, and my Dart installation doesn't understand it.

Comment: @DarshanComputing See chapter 12.8.1 of the spec.

Comment: @Ladicek Ah, I found it, thanks.  Interesting that it's not a keyword, and it's currently implemented using `throw`.

Comment: @DarshanComputing It used to be just `throw`, but it was changed to `rethrow` some time ago.

Comment: @Ladicek You mean in the spec?  Ah, that makes sense.  Perhaps in the M4 release the VM, dart2js, etc. will switch.  Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Current versions of the Dart VM and `dart2js` support rethrowing, preserving the stack trace, with `rethrow`:

```dart
void main() {
  try {
    try {
      throw 1;
    } catch (e, s) {
      print("$e $s");
      rethrow;
    }
  } catch (e2, s2) {
    print("$e2 $s2");    
  }
}
```

This produces:

```
1 #0      main (file:///home/darshan/so/stacktrace.dart:4:7)

1 #0      main (file:///home/darshan/so/stacktrace.dart:4:7)
#1      main (file:///home/darshan/so/stacktrace.dart:7:7)
```

Comment: So - the difference is that you just `throw` and @JustinFagnani is doing `throw e` ?

Comment: @Jasper Yes, `throw e;` is a normal throw, while `throw;` is the current way of writing `rethrow;`.