# Dart What is the difference between throw and rethrow?

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, try-catch, throw

It might be obvious, but I still fail to understand the difference between `throw` and `rethrow` and when do either of those should be used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use-rethrow-to-rethrow-a-caught-exception):

> If you decide to rethrow an exception, prefer using the `rethrow` statement instead of throwing the same exception object using `throw`. `rethrow` preserves the original stack trace of the exception. `throw` on the other hand resets the stack trace to the last thrown position.

The biggest difference is the preservation of the original stack trace.

---

They provided 2 examples to show the intended usage:

Bad:

```dart
try {
  somethingRisky();
} catch (e) {
  if (!canHandle(e)) throw e;
  handle(e);
}
```

Good:

```dart
try {
  somethingRisky();
} catch (e) {
  if (!canHandle(e)) rethrow;
  handle(e);
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I found when looking on Google, still didn't understand, when I looked are ResoCoder's video on handling exception I got all the more confused.

Comment: @TersterWordp What don't you understand?

Comment: If I used ```throw e``` instead of ```rethrow``` what would change in the stackTrace? 
Could you provide a personal example of when you would use either of those?

Comment: @TersterWordp [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028565/how-do-i-rethrow-an-exception-and-preserve-the-stack-trace) shows an example of where the original stacktrace is lost and the answer shows how rethrow preserves it. Just trying something like this and looking at the difference in stacktraces will make it obvious.

Answer (score 2):

It's abit late to respond but I guess it will help someone at the present or in the future.
Throw and Rethrow for Handling Exceptions.

`throw` keyword is used when you encounter an exception and you intiate a process of raising an exception just within you code. More of signaling that an exception has occured.

`rethrow` keyword is used when you want to propagate your exception up the stack. More like you catch an exception and perform some handling and propagate to a higher level handler which is within the stack.

**Summry**

`throw`

- Is used in the creation and signaling of an exception.

`rethrow`

- Is used where an exception is caught and probably handled at a point considered low level and then propagate the same exception to a higher level handler.
- Good in handling exceptions at multiple levels, and still preserving the original exception, valuable for debugging and troubleshooting.